# How to get IIS AppPool Worker Process ID

Tags: iis, powershell, automation

I have a PowerShell script that is run automatically when our monitoring service detects that a website is down.
It is supposed to stop the AppPool (using `Stop-WebAppPool -name $AppPool;`), wait until it is really stopped and then restart it.

Sometimes it the process does not actually stop, manifested by the error

```
Cannot Start Application Pool:  
The service cannot accept control messages at this time.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070425)"
```

when you try to start it again.

If it takes longer than a certain number of seconds to stop (I will chose that amount of time after I have timed several stops to see how long it usually takes), I want to just kill the process.

I know that I can get the list of processes used by workers in the AppPool by doing `dir IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool\WorkerProcesses\`,

```
Process ID  State      Handles  Start Time
----------  -----      -------  ----------
7124        Running
```

but I can't figure out how to actually capture the process id so I can kill it.

Comment: What OS are you using?  I dont see that option on Windows 7

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I need to do the following on Win7 box:  
    import-module WebAdministration

Comment: Server 2008 R2 Web. I do not remember whether I had to manually import that module.

Comment: I just checked.  You do have to import the module under Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In case that Process ID is really the id of process to kill, you can:

```
$id = dir IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool\WorkerProcesses\ | Select-Object -expand processId
Stop-Process -id $id
```

or

```
dir IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool\WorkerProcesses\ | % { Stop-Process -id $_.processId }
```

Comment: I wish I could vote this up twice. I did not know about the `%` shortcut for `foreach-object`.

Comment: Originally I wanted to use `Foreach-Object` but as you know `dir`, I thought you are familiar with aliases. Other aliases can be found via `Get-Alias` :)

Comment: I already knew some of them, since they are that same as dos/bash. The full list is great though.

Comment: Keep in mind, the IIS:\ provider will cache the workerprocess information.  In cases where you application pools are reset often, the process IDs will change.  This will not be sufficient.

Comment: @tuxedo25  Here is powershell command I use instead:  

    Get-WmiObject -NameSpace 'root\WebAdministration'  -class 'WorkerProcess' -ComputerName 'LocalHost' | select AppPoolName, ProcessId

Comment: The caching issue caught me for a good while: processId returned from the provider did not match that from Get-WmiObject

Comment: @tuxedo25 Do you, or anyone know how to clear that cache?  I'm running into this problem now.  I see that there is a method ClearLocalCache() for the object, but when I run that, I get an error.
PS IIS:\AppPools\Test\WorkerProcesses> (dir "IIS:\AppPools\Test\WorkerProcesses").ClearLocalData()
Exception calling "ClearLocalData" with "0" argument(s): "The configuration object is read only, because it has been 
committed by a call to ServerManager.CommitChanges(). If write access is required, use ServerManager to get a new 
reference."

Comment: Imho the safest way is to run PowerShell.exe with the command. So new powershell instance is created without anything cached.

Comment: After this "Kill" I was need to Stop/Start pool manually, but anyway, this method works! Thanx!

Comment: Note:  Sometimes, there won't be a running worker process, so `$id` will be null.  So either check that `$id` is not null before passing it to `Stop-Process`, or just stick with the second version, which uses `ForEach-Object`.

Answer (score 16):

In Command Prompt on the server, I just do the following for a list of running AppPool PIDs so I can kill them with taskkill or Task Mgr:

```
cd c:\windows\system32\inetsrv
appcmd list wp
```

```
taskkill /f /pid *PIDhere*
```

Comment: The commands provided by PandaCookie are perfect for identifying which IIS worker process is associated with each website so that you don't have to kill them all if you have a problem with only one on a webserver. You can identify the right one and end that one only.

Comment: `.\appcmd list wp`

Answer (score 12):

(Adding answer from Roman's comment, since there maybe cache issues with stej's solution)

Open Powershell as an Administrator on the web server, then run:

```
gwmi -NS 'root\WebAdministration' -class 'WorkerProcess' | select AppPoolName,ProcessId
```

You should see something like:

```
AppPoolName ProcessId
----------- ---------
AppPool_1        8020
AppPool_2        8568
```

You can then use Task Manager to kill it or in Powershell use:

```
Stop-Process -Id xxxx
```

---

If you get **Get-WmiObject : Could not get objects from namespace root/WebAdministration. Invalid namespace** then you need to enable the **IIS Management Scripts and Tools** feature using:

```
ipmo ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools
```

Comment: Ok but how do I get the PID for "AppPool_1" into a variable that I can use to kill that process in a batch?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and here is my solution:

```
Get-WmiObject –class win32_process -filter 'name="w3wp.exe"' | Select-Object –Property Name, ProcessId, @{n='AppPool';e={$_.GetOwner().user}} | Where-Object {$_.AppPool -eq "WebsiteName"} | Select-Object -expand ProcessId
```