# kill IIS worker process by sitename

Tags: powershell, iis

for this question, "site names" = what IIS calls a site's name.  E.G, the output of:

```
ls IIS:\Sites\ | select Name
```

Given a text file with these site names, I'd like to iterate through all running w3wp.exe processes, and then kill (not recycle, kill) all w3wp.exe processes not associated with a site name in the list.  (my list is NOT the output of ls IIS:\Sites\ | select Name btw, that's just an example to define what we are calling "site names".  My list is a list of site names that *should be* running on the server, created manually)

I can kill all w3wp.exe's with

```
taskkill /IM w3wp.exe /F
```

but I'm struggling to make the connection between IIS site names, and their associated worker processes so I can kill specific ones based on site names.  I'm guessing I need to go siteName>appPool>worker process...but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Any specific reason you aren't using the `WebAdministration` module and `Stop-WebSite` cmdlet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get IIS AppPool Worker Process ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014536/how-to-get-iis-apppool-worker-process-id)

Answer (score 0):

```
$workerProcesses = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='w3wp.exe'"
foreach ($workerProcess in $workerProcesses)
{
    $wpSiteName = $workerProcess.CommandLine.split(" ")[2].replace("`"","")
    $wpPID = $workerProcess.ProcessId

    if ($myListNotShownHere -notcontains $wpSiteName)
    {
        #taskkill /f /pid $wpPID   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of killing the worker process, you can also just stop the site. This is more performance-friendly since no process has to be killed and restarted.

As already commented by @Eris, you can do this using the WebAdministration module:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Stop-Website -Name "MySite"
```

You need to run PowerShell with elevated status in order to use the WebAdministration module.

If you **really must** kill the worker process, see stej's answer here: [How to get IIS AppPool Worker Process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014536/how-to-get-iis-apppool-worker-process-id)